# existence of neighborhood of $a$ such that $rank(Df(x))=m, \forall x \in V$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations

Let be $f:A \subset \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m $ of class $C^1$ and $rank(df(a))=m$
Prove that exist V neighborhood of a such that
$$rank(Df(x))=m, \forall x \in V$$
Is this true if $m \neq n$ ?
The case when m=n is true because we can apply the determinant $Det(Df(a)) \neq 0$ and by continuity there exist a neightborhood V where $$Det(Df(x)) \neq 0, \forall x \in V$$
Hence $rank(Df(x))=m, \forall x \in V$

Comment: You can do a modification of the same proof when $n>m$. What is an analogous characterization of the rank if a non-square matrix?

Comment: @TedShifrin you mean restricting to a subspace of dimension m and applying the determinant there

Comment: Yes … Or, what is the same, look at some $m\times m$ submatrix.